# Dart/Flutter Alternative to PHP's resize_crop_image?

Tags: php, image, flutter, dart, image-processing

Currently, I am resizing avatars on my server using PHP's resize_crop_image. The code below takes an image, crops and resizes it so that it's exactly 500px X 500px square.

resize_crop_image(500, 500, $filename, $filename);

But I'd like to move this process from the server to the flutter app. Most of the plugins I'm seeing on pub.dev are overkill with the user cropping the image using a crop tool. But I'd like this function to happen automatically the way I currently do it in PHP.

Here's the resize_crop_image code;

```
function resize_crop_image($max_width, $max_height, $source_file, $dst_dir, $quality = 100){
        $imgsize = getimagesize($source_file);
        $width = $imgsize[0];
        $height = $imgsize[1];
        $mime = $imgsize['mime'];
     
        switch($mime){
            case 'image/gif':
                $image_create = "imagecreatefromgif";
                $image = "imagegif";
                break;
     
            case 'image/png':
                $image_create = "imagecreatefrompng";
                $image = "imagepng";
                $quality = 10;
                break;
     
            case 'image/jpeg':
                $image_create = "imagecreatefromjpeg";
                $image = "imagejpeg";
                $quality = 100;
                break;
     
            default:
                return false;
                break;
        }
         
        $dst_img = imagecreatetruecolor($max_width, $max_height);
        $src_img = $image_create($source_file);
         
        $width_new = $height * $max_width / $max_height;
        $height_new = $width * $max_height / $max_width;
        //if the new width is greater than the actual width of the image, then the height is too large and the rest cut off, or vice versa
        if($width_new > $width){
            //cut point by height
            $h_point = (($height - $height_new) / 2);
            //copy image
            imagecopyresampled($dst_img, $src_img, 0, 0, 0, $h_point, $max_width, $max_height, $width, $height_new);
        }else{
            //cut point by width
            $w_point = (($width - $width_new) / 2);
            imagecopyresampled($dst_img, $src_img, 0, 0, $w_point, 0, $max_width, $max_height, $width_new, $height);
        }
         
        $image($dst_img, $dst_dir, $quality);
     
        if($dst_img)imagedestroy($dst_img);
        if($src_img)imagedestroy($src_img);
    }      
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this library: [flutter_native_image](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_image#flutter_native_image) for resizing/croping your images.

Important to take a look at the other parameters of this function, you can probably customize the way the image will be cropped.

Something like that:

```dart
ImageProperties properties = await FlutterNativeImage.getImageProperties(file.path);
File croppedFile = await FlutterNativeImage.cropImage(file.path, originX, originY, 500, 500);
```

originX/originY: x/y position for the cut.

Comment: Any idea what I should use for originX, originY if I want it to be cropped exactly from the center?

Comment: i think the crop function is used to cut the image from the originX/originY with that width and height. `FlutterNativeImage.compressImage` don't works?

Comment: I'm not sure why I would compress an image to do a crop? I'm guessing I can find the center like thus; int originX= properties.width  ~/ 2; int originY = properties.height  ~/ 2;

Comment: But I'm a bit confused about the parameters to pass to the crop function. I'm taking an image off the internet to crop so I've got a URL/filepath but not sure what to use for  File image; Here's what I've got so far;  cropAvatar(File image, filepath)async{
  ImageProperties properties = await FlutterNativeImage.getImageProperties(filepath);
  int originX= properties.width  ~/ 2;
  int originY = properties.height  ~/ 2;

  File croppedFile = await FlutterNativeImage.cropImage(filepath, originX, originY, 500, 500);
  return croppedFile;
}

Comment: i think if you use crop, it will cut a part from the original image, loosing a good part of it, thats why i think u need to resize the image. But if u want to just cut part of it, the originalX/Y is the initial point u want to cut, probably 0.

Comment: I want the final image to be square and sized to exactly 500px X 500x. If it's a portrait orientation an equal amount must be cut from top and bottom. If it's a landscape orientation an equal amount must be cut from the left and right sides.

Comment: How do I pass an URL to flutter_native_image  instead of an image file ?

Comment: ok, so you need to calculate the initial x and y positions and pass to the function as originX/Y and 500 as width and height. To convert a URL to file: [https://mrgulshanyadav.medium.com/convert-image-url-to-file-format-in-flutter-10421bccfd18](https://mrgulshanyadav.medium.com/convert-image-url-to-file-format-in-flutter-10421bccfd18)